# Error getting the first property in a PHP array to use in a switch statement

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

Am working on an array response in PHP Laravel whereby I get multiple sets of data in the response. For instance inside the array, the 1st element of the array may be **regional manager** or **city manager** or **local manager**.  Am getting the response in the form of a JSON object and converting it to a PHP array. Next,, I am trying to write a switch statement to check if the 1st array key is a certain value, then redirect to a specific view. 
The problem is that am finding it a bit difficult to use the switch to test for the first value in the array

**Controller that contains response am getting and the switch statement in it**

```
public function getAgentHierachy(){

        $resp = GeneralHelper::global_Curl([],'api/v1/b2b/life/agent-hierarchy')->data;

        //Converting from JSON object to PHP array
        $rs =  json_decode(json_encode($resp),true);

        $result = '';

        switch($rs)
        {
            case $rs->regional_manager:

                $result = view('pages.general.pol', compact('rs'));
            break;

            case $rs->city_manager:

                $result = view('B2B::pages.general.pol', compact('rs'));
            break;

            case $rs->local_manager:

                $result = view('B2B::pages.general.pol', compact('rs'));

            break;

        }

        return $result;               
    }
```

**Sample data I may get as a response containing different cases**

```
array:1 [▼
  "regional_manager" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
]

array:1 [▼
  "city_manager" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
]

array:1 [▼
  "local_manager" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really how a switch statement works, as you've already identified you're looking to run a switch on the array key NOT the array itself, the following should help:

```
$allArrayKeys = array_keys($rs); // get all keys
switch ($allArrayKeys[0]) { // switch whatever is the first key
    case 'regional_manager':
      // Do stuff for this case here...
     break;
    case 'city_manager':
      // Do stuff for this case here...
      break;
    case 'local_manager':
      // Do stuff for this case here...
      break;
}
```

Comment: Use `var_dump($rs);` to check what you're actually passing into the array_keys function, the error is very clear that you're giving it an object instead of an array, my solution was working based on the array example you gave. If you have an object you can cast it to an array like so `$rs = (array) $rs;` however you really need to be understanding the data you have before attempting to work on it.

Comment: Thanks alot,, I had not passed a 2nd parameter,, it now works well. Would you mind in assisting me in another issue?? When I pass it to the response to the blade.. I dump on the browser,, I get a collection of JSON objects,, I need to iterate through the object and get keys so as to display to the view..

Comment: @Martin might be worth checking some existing answers for that, or doing a little reading up on arrays / json objects or looking into laravel's docs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `true` as the second argument from `json_decode()` function then you will be able to access json data in object form as you did in your switch case.

```
$rs =  json_decode(json_encode($resp));
```

On a side note:
I guess you are passing wrong argument in `switch()`

Edit - 01: you could modify your code to look something like following:

```
        $viewName = $res = '';
        $str = 'regional_manager';
        switch($str)
        {
            case 'regional_manager':
                $res = $rs->regional_manager;
                $viewName = 'pages.general.pol';
            break;

            /*
              and so on
             */

        } //switch case ends
        $result = view($viewName,compact('res'));
        return $result;
```

Comment: ,, Thanks for help,, am not sure about it,, would you kindly explain via an example

Comment: Your switch wouldn't work as you're manually setting the string to 'regional manager' so there's nothing to actually switch.

Comment: it's an example not the exact implementation.

Comment: @dexter I understood,, your method also works,, thanks alot